# Strategy For Scheduling Email Alerts in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, task-queue

I'm writing a PHP project in Laravel. The admin can queue email alerts to be sent at a specific date/time. The natural choice was to use Laravel's Queue class with Beanstalkd (Laravel uses Pheanstalk internally).

However, the admin can choose to reschedule or delete email alerts that have not yet been sent. I could not find a way yet to delete a specific task so that I can insert a new one with the new timing.

What is the usual technique to accomplish something like this? I'm open to other ideas as well. I don't want to use CRON since the volumes of these emails would be pretty high, and I'd rather reuse an already tested solution for managing a task queue.

Answer (score 4):

I have scoured the internet for such an answer myself.

Here's what I've found:

### Beanstalkd

I think the simplest way within Beantalkd is to use its ability to delay a job (giving it a number of seconds to delay as an argument).

You can then do date math to capture the difference in time between `now()` and when the job ideally is run (in seconds) and delay the job that long.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731419/how-can-i-schedule-an-email-to-be-sent-at-some-point-in-the-future-in-django) (see first answer to that SO question - it's in Python, but you can get the gist of what the person is saying/doing)

Note that this doesn't guarantee the task is run on time - the delay just make the job available after X seconds. How behind your queue is on processing tasks when the delayed job becomes available determines when the job is run in reality. (If you're queue is behind due to heavy number of jobs, then it won't necessarily run exactly on time!)

#### Laravel

Laravel's Queue has a [later](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Queue/BeanstalkdQueue.php#L60) method, which you can use instead of `push`

Where as with Push, you'd do:

```
Queue::push('Some\Processing\Class', array('data' => $data));
```

with `later()`, you'd do:

```
$delay = 14400; // 4 hours in seconds
Queue::later($delay, 'Some\Processing\Class', array('data' => $data));
```

### SaaS Options

1. [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/?csw=1) can schedule tasks
2. [iron.io](http://dev.iron.io/worker/scheduling/) can schedule tasks (works well with Laravel!)

### Other languages

1. Python's [Celery](http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown) has similar options to delay jobs (with the same caveats)
2. Ruby's resque has a [schedular](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) that also sort of fits this

Comment: That's correct. However, I wanted to know about a way to alter an already queued job. Let's say I queue a job to run in 24 hours, but I wish to alter it to run in 36 hours instead, then how do I cancel a previous scheduled job? Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. Store job ID's in a database so you can refer to them later perhaps? I'm not sure a "get job by id" functionality exists.

Comment: This is a few days old, did you guys find a solution / know if there is that functionality now?

Comment: This is a 3 years old , actually . There is a database driver for laravel queues now, which might help. @hogan

Comment: Yeah, maybe should have written 'once upon a time' instead ;) so you suggest using that and then manipulating the available_at by id, right?